# Required parameters in apiary is not required

Tags: apiblueprint, apiary

I'm triing to create my api with apiary (apiblueprint) but I always get 201 response when I send a post data to my endpoint. But endpoint requires some parameter, so when I send empty post I should get some error message. How may I do it?

```
### Create a New Question [POST]

+ question `Some text message` (string, required)

+ Request (application/json)

    {
        "question": "Favourite programming language?",
        "choices": [
            "Swift",
            "Python",
            "Objective-C",
            "Ruby"
        ]
    }

+ Response 201 (application/json)

    + Headers

        Location: /questions/2

    + Body

        {
            "question": "Faavourite programming language?",
            "published_at": "2015-08-05T08:40:51.620Z",
            "choices": [
                {
                    "choice": "Swift",
                    "votes": 0
                }, {
                    "choice": "Python",
                    "votes": 0
                }, {
                    "choice": "Objective-C",
                    "votes": 10
                }, {
                    "choice": "Ruby",
                    "votes": 0
                }
            ]
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are sending your POST request to Apiary's mock server, you will get back the first response that is specified for that endpoint in your API Blueprint. This means you will always get a 201 in your example even when it does not match your data structure.

However, Apiary will inspect your request and ensure that it matches your data structures and schemas, letting you know where it is invalid.

Your request includes a question parameter in the JSON, and Apiary will ensure that it's there when a request is made. It will however treat this line as the description of your action and not use it when inspecting:

```
+ question `Some text message` (string, required)
```

The recommended way to define data structures is to use [MSON](https://help.apiary.io/api_101/mson-tutorial/) as shown below (note I did not convert the response to MSON, only the request):

```
### Create a New Question [POST]

+ Request (application/json)
    + Attributes
        + question (string, required)
        + choices (array, optional)
            - Swift
            - Python
            - Objective-C
            - Ruby

+ Response 201 (application/json)

    + Headers

            Location: /questions/2

    + Body

            {
                "question": "Favourite programming language?",
                "published_at": "2015-08-05T08:40:51.620Z",
                "choices": [
                    {
                        "choice": "Swift",
                        "votes": 0
                    }, {
                        "choice": "Python",
                        "votes": 0
                    }, {
                        "choice": "Objective-C",
                        "votes": 0
                    }, {
                        "choice": "Ruby",
                        "votes": 0
                    }
                ]
            }
```

If you use this example, make a request to the mock server while leaving out the `question` property, and then view the "Inspector" tab, you will see a note that the `question` property was left out.

[image: Missing Question Property]

While MSON is our recommended way to define data structures, you can also use [JSON Schema](https://github.com/apiaryio/api-blueprint/blob/f24c663caf24730f118778803013bf60ff3075f7/examples/14.%20JSON%20Schema.md) to define your semantics.

Comment: Thanks Stephen, but I don't understand why I need to use MSON for that? When I open inspector now (without any modification) I can also see there is missing required parameter. So I can not see any advantage to use MSON now?

Comment: So if I understand well there is no way to get response depend on request? I get always same response? Thanks

Comment: @John Different question, but yes you can: http://support.apiary.io/knowledgebase/articles/117119-handling-multiple-actions-on-a-single-resource & standard content negotiation.

Comment: @John You are right that MSON is not required. I updated my response to convey this. The reason you see that message that `question` is missing is because you have a question property in your request JSON—not because you have defined question as required. That line is not used by Apiary other than as a description for your action.